# Exclude items from Rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Update, the solution is:
>   `params['place']['menu_items_attributes'].reject! { |_, v|
>   v['id'].empty? }`

Problem — I would like to exclude certain items from params but don't know how.

Background. A place has many menu items. On the edit page you can add new items using javascript: I clone the first existing node and replace ID with a random number (e.g. 1532174166502). In order to save those generated items you must submit the form.

When you submit the form I search through params for menu items with empty ID and create them. After that, I update everything else.

Rails fails to properly update everything because my handmade menu items (in params) don't have an ID (it is obviously blank). I would like to exclude those newly created menu items.

```
before_action :find_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :add_menu_items, only: [:update]

# PATCH/PUT /admin/places/:id
def update
  if @place.update(place_params)
    render json: {}, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {}, status: :internal_server_error
  end
end

# The error
# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with ID=1 for MenuItem with ID=)

# Params
# {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"rOgxn...uitQ==", "place"=>{"menu_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"product_attributes"=>{"id"=>"7"}, "price"=>"23", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"30"}, "1532174157580"=>{"product_attributes"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "price"=>"999", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>""}, "1"=>{"product_attributes"=>{"id"=>"11"}, "price"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"31"}, "1532174166502"=>{"product_attributes"=>{"id"=>"10"}, "price"=>"666", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>""}}}, "menu_item_type"=>"foods", "menu_item_category"=>"desert", "menu_item_product"=>"10", "reset"=>"Reset", "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"admin/places", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"7"}
```

I've tried to iterate through params with .reject (found in docs), but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the value of `place_params`, right before the `@place.update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

existing menu item:

```
params["place"]["menu_items_attributes"].select {|k, v| !v["id"].empty? }
```

new menu item:

```
params["place"]["menu_items_attributes"].select {|k, v| v["id"].empty? }
```

I don't know your case, might be you want this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  params["place"]["menu_items_attributes"].select {|k, v| v["id"].empty? }.values.each do |menu_item_param|
    MenuItem.create!(menu_item_param)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't try params['place']['menu_items_attributes'].reject! { |_, v| v['id'].empty? } before — it solved my problem! How did you came up with the use of ActiveRecord::Base.transaction?

Comment: it is to make sure that every menu item records created successfully, otherwise the records will be deleted from database, and you can ask customer to fix the errors